# How to read *.txt file with non-english letters using c++? (internationalization)

Tags: c++, c++11, internationalization

I have a written code which reads text from a file and counts words and how many times they were repeated, as well as cout'ing URL links. But I do not know how make code read Lithuanian letters. I did not find a clear answer to this question on the internet. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far? it is also important to know what operating system you are using since the answer depends on that too.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio. I am still a beginner, so I could not find any short or not too complicated information I could apply (plus English is not my first language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important question is what [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is used. You should know that. Today, in 2020, it is recommended to use [UTF8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) or at least something related to [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

But some computers or operating systems use other character encodings. You need to find out (perhaps by contacting the human who gave your that file) which encoding is used, or by reading documentation related to your system.

If you are sure the encoding *is* UTF-8, you'll find libraries to deal with it. Including [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) (look also into [Qt](https://qt.io/), [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) and other ones, perhaps on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)).

Be aware that some non-latin letters take several bytes of UTF-8 encoding. For example, the Russian letter <kbd>*Ж*</kbd> (U+0416 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ZHE) is UTF-8 encoded with two bytes:  `0xD0` `0x96`, and the very common French letter <kbd>*é*</kbd> (U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE) is UTF-8 encoded with `0xC3` `0xA9`

Hence [*Jūratė*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%ABrat%C4%97) needs 8 bytes in UTF-8. So `sizeof("Jūratė")`  is likely to give 9 (with most C++ compilers accepting UTF-8 literal strings on x86-64).

See also https://home.unicode.org/

Don't forget to read a good [C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book, and see also this [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Read the documentation of your C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) and don't confuse it with your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (such as [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)). Read also the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Comment: Thank you! I checked now, it is UTF-8. Guess I'll start searching for the right method to apply in my code now.